# How to return column headers for all columns which match search criteria?

Tags: google-sheets, unique, google-sheets-formula

Football coaches here... and a [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m0qQRG1XMqoR5smvrlxFHT2qrGzaRQXnOC7YvxcqX7Y/edit?usp=sharing) listing our plays available by formation.

We would like to create a complimentary sheet that will list formations possible under each play. Ultimately, we'd like to enter a term, say `26/27 Hit` and have it return all possible formations to run that from.

More specifically for the sheet, we'd like to return column headers from all columns which match the search terms from a cell.

Comment: Your spreadsheet share is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Sheet2!A2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(IF(A1=Sheet1!A2:F22,Sheet1!A1:F1&"","")),"")))
```

A1= Key
A2 will provide headers.

Answer (score 0):

I added a Sheet3 that makes a unique list of the plays. Put this in Sheet3 A1

=unique(sort(transpose(Split(join(",",Sheet1!A2:A,Sheet1!B2:B,Sheet1!C2:C,Sheet1!D2:D,Sheet1!E2:E,Sheet1!F2:F),",")),1,true))

It is what the Data validation uses in Sheet2 A2 (Sheet3!A1:A1000Sheet3!A1:A1000).

Put this in Sheet2 B2. It finds the fornation of the play selected from the dropdown list.

=transpose(split(arrayformula(textjoin(",",true,if(Sheet1!A2:F=A2,Sheet1!A1:F,""))),","))

If you add new formations, you will need to add them to the formulas, but added plays will 
pick up as added.

Here is an example you can copy and try.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ynj06aIQE4y-LjKcR7_YJ01LpnjvFuEpJbx98qyreGc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you. The Sheet2 returns two plays, maybe I accidentally changed something, but I used your Sheet 3 formula to populate a dropdown option for Sheet 2!